# Indexing a list a element

Tags: python, string, list, indexing, positioning

Can you please help me here

Given a list of words (I.e. this list can take any number of strings, and strings are randomly positioned):

```
List1 = ['ENG', 'ENG', 'NEUTRAL' , 'TSO', 'ENG', 'TSO' ]
```

OR

```
List2 = ['NEUTRAL', 'NEUTRAL', 'ENG', 'ENG', 'NEUTRAL' , 'TSO', 'ENG', 'TSO', 'NEUTRAL']
```

I want to define the in index of this list. The index of NEUTRAL string must be -1. The index of other strings must be 0, 1, etc. In this order.

E.g. in list1, the index must be indexes = `[0, 1, -1, 2, 3, 4]`.
List 2 indexes must be indexes = `[-1, -1, 0, 1, -1, 2, 3, 4, -1]`

Here is my attempt:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `itertools.count` to generate the counter and a list comprehension:

```
from itertools import count
c = count()

out = [next(c) if v!= 'NEUTRAL' else -1 for v in List1]
```

output: `[0, 1, -1, 2, 3, 4]`

output for "List2": `[-1, -1, 0, 1, -1, 2, 3, 4, -1]`

Answer (score 0):

Here is one of the approaches:

```
List1 = ['NEUTRAL', 'NEUTRAL', 'ENG', 'ENG', 'NEUTRAL' , 'TSO', 'ENG', 'TSO', 'NEUTRAL']
indexes = []
counter = 0
for element in List1:
    if element == 'NEUTRAL':
        indexes.append(-1)
    else:
        indexes.append(counter)
        counter += 1
    
print (indexes)
```

Output:

```
[-1, -1, 0, 1, -1, 2, 3, 4, -1]
```